# When to use dynamic type with generic types?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a question about good practices with dynamic keyword. Let's say that we have a specific situation:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public void DoSth() { /* ... */ }
}

public class Object1 : MyObject { /* ... */ }
public class Object2 : MyObject { /* ... */ }
public class Object3 : MyObject { /* ... */ }

public abstract class MyContainer
{
    public abstract dynamic Get(string id);
}

public class MyContainer<T>: MyContainer where T : MyObject
{
    private Dictionary<string, T> _container;
    public override dynamic Get(string id)
    {
        T result;
        _container.TryGetValue(id, out result);
        return result;
    }
}

public class MyStorage
{
    private MyContainer<Object1> _objects1;
    private MyContainer<Object1> _objects2;
    private MyContainer<Object1> _objects3;

    public Dictionary<Type, MyContainer> GetContainer;

    public MyStorage()
    {
        GetContainer = new Dictionary<Type, MyContainer>() 
        {
            { typeof(Object1), _objects1 },
            { typeof(Object2), _objects2 },
            { typeof(Object3), _objects3 }
        }
    }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        MyStorage storage = new MyStorage();
        // defining a sotrage ...

        Type objectType = //let's say we have it
        string objectId = //let's say we have it

        (storage.GetContainer[objectType].Get(objectId) as MyObject).DoSth();
    }
}
```

Does it look OK that I return a dynamic value in the "Get" method and convert it to MyObject anyway? Or maybe there is no problem with dynamic keyword but in the whole concept to create a storage like that (keeping functionality of getting objects by type and identifier)?

Comment: There seems to be no necessity to use dynamic since the constrain is to be MyObject. Dynamic is for situations where the type is not known at runtime

Comment: Ok, Then the code is good if I just replace MyObject type instead of dynamic?

Comment: I won't say never, ever, ever use `dynamic`. Just almost never, ever, ever.

Comment: " Then the code is good" I would not dare to evaluate that :)  But replacing it with `MyObject` would surely make it more robust

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `dynamic` here. You can simplify `MyContainer` and make it more useful by making it a unconstrained generic and having `Get` return a `T`:

```
  public class MyContainer<T>
  {
    private Dictionary<string, T> _container;
    public T Get(string id)
    {
      T result;
      _container.TryGetValue(id, out result);
      return result;
    }
  }
```

This way, you don't need an abstract class and you don't need any type constraints, `MyContainer` will work with any type. If you do want to constrain it for some reason, you could change the class definition to:

```
public class MyContainer<T> where T: MyObject
```

But, doing that would waste the whole purpose of having a generic class. You might as well make `MyContainer` non-generic and replace any references to `T` with `MyObject`.

Comment: But If I use MyObject instead of "T" here then I have to cast to Object1, Object2, Object3 every time I want to get their own properties/methods/etc.